# Using business experience of the seller by a young buyer corporation to bid works/contract with a PSU

Tags: contract-law, business, government-contracts

Company A, an existing multinational for 10 years, enters into a Business Transfer Agreement with a small Indian firm, B, incorporated in 2019.

Can B quote the experience of A in last ten years (completed before the date of Busines Transfer) to bid for a work or contract with a company, say, a PSU?

Comment: What country is this contract in? Is B going to use the resources of A to complete this contract? Is the contract with a government entity?

Comment: B is incorporated in India, and the BTA took place in India. A and B are affiliates of the parent company based in the UK. As part of business restructuring, A did a BTA agreement to transfer only works of the Indian office to B. Whether B can use the work experience and resources of A remains to be seen. One can safely assume that the work experience of only the Indian office of A can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the correct thing to do would be to describe in detail the expertise that the the young firm has available to it and the means by which is has gained access to it so as not to be misleading.

Otherwise, a claim of tens years experience from a two year old firm would seem absurd and could cause the contract proposal to be dismissed out of hand.

Comment: B is incorporated in India, and the BTA took place in India. A and B are affiliates of the parent company based in the UK. As part of business restructuring, A did a BTA agreement to transfer only works of the Indian office to B. Whether B can use the work experience and resources of A needs to be clarified with B as part of post-bid query. Thanks